# Permission Management Algorithm

Tags: algorithms, permissions

I have 3 levels of permission to see the product:

- `Brand` -> Allow/Deny
- `Category` -> Allow/Deny
- `Product` -> Allow/Deny

For example, product A has:

- Category: Allow
- Product: Deny

=> product A cannot be seen because product A isn't allowed in `Product` level.

```
if(allowForCategory == true) {
    if(allowForProduct == false) return false;
    if(allowForProduct == true) return true;
} else {
    ...
}
```

This is not a good choice because it will become more complex if we add brand level.

```
if() {
    if() {
        if() {}
    }
}
```

So is there any general algorithm to deal with the permission problem just like `777` solution in Linux?

Comment: What's the matter with just adding the boolean values to a list and then checking the list to contain only `true` items? Works for any number of permissions, and if you're in a functional language you can `fold` it right down into a single `if`.

Comment: Why not just AND the 3 boolean values? You can check the result with a single if statement.